# MIPS assembly language if else statement

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips

I am new to MIPS assembly language and i have a question that how can we write a program in Assembly language which will have information of a product and when we run program it should ask for the name of product and after entering name it should display all information. like in c++ we simply make if else statement and then cout the information.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional execution is handled in MIPS assembly via the `beq` and `bne` instructions. So,

```
beq $r1 $r2 8
```

looks at the registers $r1 and $r2 and, if their contents are equal, branches ahead 36 bytes (4 + 4 * 8) -- the first 4 is so that you can have whatever other instruction you want, usually a `jr`, "jump" instruction before the branch jumps back in. `bne` is similar except it branches if they *aren't* equal.

You won't find high-level control-flow concepts like `if` or `for` or `while` in any assembly language; you have to build them out of comparisons, branches, and jumps.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the program in C and then let the compiler translate it to assembly for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
  int num; 
  printf("Enter a product to check.\n"); 
  scanf("%d",&num); 
  if(num==12) printf("Number=%d\n",num); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Assembly:

```
 # GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404 (mips-mips-ecoff) compiled by GNU C version cygnus-2.7.2-970404.
 # options passed:  -msoft-float
 # options enabled:  -fpeephole -ffunction-cse -fkeep-static-consts
 # -fpcc-struct-return -fcommon -fverbose-asm -fgnu-linker -msoft-float
 # -meb -mcpu=3000

gcc2_compiled.:
__gnu_compiled_c:
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC0:
    .ascii  "Enter a product to check.\n\000"
    .sdata
    .align  2
$LC1:
    .ascii  "%d\000"
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC2:
    .ascii  "Number=%d\n\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,32,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 2/0, args= 16, extra= 0
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    subu    $sp,$sp,32
    sw  $31,28($sp)
    sw  $fp,24($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    jal __main
    la  $4,$LC0
    jal printf
    la  $4,$LC1
    addu    $5,$fp,16
    jal scanf
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    li  $3,12           # 0x0000000c
    bne $2,$3,$L2
    la  $4,$LC2
    lw  $5,16($fp)
    jal printf
$L2:
    move    $2,$0
    j   $L1
$L1:
    move    $sp,$fp         # sp not trusted here
    lw  $31,28($sp)
    lw  $fp,24($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,32
    j   $31
    .end    main
```

Comment: not really pure assembly, you still need functions from the C standard library, according to the OP question this will not work out that well.